# Routing audio from YT to Bitwig

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, jack

My first post If you need any more system info or anything then please let me know.

I have everything set up and working together pulse, jack qjack alsa etc and I can play a track on YT or other web sites and monitor through Bitwig so I can grab a sample etc.

However, sometimes I like to watch old movies on YT and route the audio through Bitwig so I can effect the audio though an Equaliser as many have really poor sound.

When I used Windows I ran this via https://vb-audio.com/Cable/ which meant I only heard the audio routed into the DAW.. ableton at that time and therefore didn't hear the YT audio directly.

For some reason though now on Ubuntu 20.04 and I cant seem to find a way to only hear the sound from the DAW and not have any volume on Youtube with Chrome itself..

So to sum up At the mo I have sound coming from Chrome and Bitwig simultaneously. I only want to hear it through Bitwig to get the effects of the EQ. Is this possible?

As a side note, I just installed PulseEffects which does exactly what I need for the purpose of allowing me to alter bass etc on the fly to just watch a movie etc but there must be a way to achieve it with Bitwig.

Many thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: Did you try turning off the sound in Chrome for the tab involved?

Comment: Hi yes Ty david but I find that turns down the monitored audio in Bitwig..

Comment: as an update to this..  Ive gone over to Lubuntu from this weekend and its running hell of a lot faster than Ubuntu did but still have this issue with sound from the net coming through. Is there a line I should be adding to pulse config or something?